# How do I do greater than/less than using MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, database

I'm using the pymongo driver.

Can someone take a look at pymongo and tell me how to do greater than? I"m used to doing : for everything.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have you seen [the doc](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#range-queries) ? Take from the manual :

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 12, 12)
>>> for post in posts.find({"date": {"$lt": d}}).sort("author"):
...   post
...
{u'date': datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 10, 10, 45), u'text': u'and pretty easy too!', u'_id': ObjectId('...'), u'author': u'Eliot', u'title': u'MongoDB is fun'}
{u'date': datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 12, 11, 14), u'text': u'Another post!', u'_id': ObjectId('...'), u'author': u'Mike', u'tags': [u'bulk', u'insert']}
```

Answer (score 30):

If you wanna query and find docs which have a field greater than something you can

```
users.find({"age": {"$gt": 20}})
```

Check out the advanced query section of Mongodb for more reference.

--Sai

Answer (score 7):

`gt` & `lt` are the operators. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart