# Remove record WHERE it is older than 10 mins in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to Node js and MongoDB (coming from an SQL background). I am trying to implement a function that removes all the records in a collection 'journeys' where the timestamp is older than 10 mins. This is what I have done so far:

```
connection.open(function(err, connection) {
    var database = connection.db(DATABASE);
    database.collection(JOURNEY_COLLECTION, {}, function(err, journeys) {
        var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000 - 10 * 60;
        journeys.remove({timestamp : ???}, function(err, result) {
            if(err != null)
                console.log('A refresh error occurred');
            connection.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Am I on the right track? What should I be putting in place of the "???" ?

Comment: Closely related: [How do I do greater than/less than using MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791555/how-do-i-do-greater-than-less-than-using-mongodb) (I know that's in Python, but the syntax is virtually identical.)

Comment: thanks. This link brought me closer. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

Comment: @user3289157 You need to use the mongodb `$gt` comparison operator. Docs are here:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/

Comment: thanks. they only mention how to pass static values though. Any idea of how to pass parameters? Like the 'now' variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Your "???" should be in the form **{$lt:varName}**

```
var tenMinutesOld = new Date()
tenMinutesOld.setMinutes(tenMinutesOld.getMinutes()-10)
journeys.remove({timestamp: {$lt:tenMinutesOld}}, function(err, result) {
```

Comment: I have edited my original answer thanks to apsillers

Comment: bam, just like that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

I'm sure someone'll post an answer that uses the example code, but I'm going to show you how to do it on a database level.

First, define a field that'll contain a Date. This can be either the creation time (method A) or when you want it removed (method B). I'll explain both, but method B is my favourite. It allows you to more easily modify the time to live. A field with the date set to `null` will not be removed.

**Method A**:

```
var someDocument = { "created": new Date() };
```

**Method B**:

```
var someDocument = { "expire": new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 60 * 1000) };
```

Add a [TTL index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) on this field, like so:

**Method A**:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex( { "created": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 600 } )
```

**Method B**:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex( { "expire": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } )
```

MongoDB runs a job every 60 seconds that looks for documents that should be removed. Due to this reason, you *might* get documents that are slightly stale.

*(Note that I've named the field 'created' (method A) / 'expire' (method B), you can name them anything but I think this is more descriptive than just 'timestamp' for these examples )*

Comment: oh wow, this is a different perspective :) how do you think this would affect the performance of the server? In other words, is it better to have a job running every 60 seconds, or an event-driven model, where the job is run every time the db is queried?

Comment: I don't have any metrics on that, sorry. In the end, both ways would end up running similar queries.