# Node.js load more using ajax call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement load more option in my node.js application. 
Want to fetch 5 records with each ajax request from mongodb Database. 
I have following mongoose query to get list of article excluding first article

`var query=Articlepost.find({status:true,content_category:req.query.type}).sort({"_id":-1}).skip(1);`

Now if i can execute query like this on every request with load more option i can think about desired output.
 But, the problem is how to get last id in mongodb with node.js express and that sort() function is working fine first time but will they work fine with second request.
Here i want to pass last_id from first query.

```
query= Articlepost.find({'_id'> last_id}). sort({"_id":-1}).limit(10);
```

Comment: It might help to do some research in the right place. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/. Noting that all of this is in Object notation. So if it doesn't look like valid Object notation then it likely is not valid. Hence why there are special "key based" operators for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do greater than/less than using MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791555/how-do-i-do-greater-than-less-than-using-mongodb)

Comment: @BlakesSeven : I am not too much concern about less than or greater than part here, My main problem is how to get the last_id from the result i got form first query so, i can pass that id next time.

Comment: Then perhaps another duplicate: [Calculate Skip value from Record for Sorted Paging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242867/calculate-skip-value-for-given-record-for-sorted-paging/31243398#31243398)